# How does one solve the following system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

$\left\{ \begin{aligned}     |x| + |y| + z &= a\\     |x| +  y + |z| &= a + 1\\     x + |y| + |z| &= a + 2\end{aligned} \right.$
The domain is $\mathbb{R}$, $a > 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When asking questions, you should always show what you did and where you got stuck so that others can help you appropriately.

Comment: For $a>1$ is the situation not so compligated.

Answer (score 1):

From the first and from the third equations we obtain:
$$x+|y|+|z|=|x|+|y|+z+2,$$
which gives
$$|z|-z=|x|-x+2\geq2$$ and from here
$$|z|\geq2+z$$ and since $$z\geq z+2$$ is impossible, we obtain:
$$z\leq -z-2$$ or $$z\leq-1.$$
Now, from the first and from the second equations we obtain:
$$|x|+y+|z|=|x|+|y|+z+1,$$ which gives
$$|y|-y=|z|-z-1\geq1+1-1\geq1,$$ which gives
$$|y|\geq1+y,$$ $$y\leq-1-y$$ or
$$y\leq-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Id est, we got the following system:
$$|x|-y+z=a,$$
$$|x|+y-z=a+1$$ and
$$x-y-z=a+2,$$ which gives $$|x|=a+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the following answer.
$$\left\{\left(a+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1\right)\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint...consider separately the cases when each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ are $\geq 0$ or $<0$. There are eight cases to consider. In all but two cases, the equations are inconsistent.

the solutions are $$(a+\frac 12,-\frac 12, -1)$$ and $$(-a-\frac 12,-a-1,-a-\frac 32)$$